# Why does Scala's RichInt extends Comparable[Int] instead of Comparable[RichInt]?

Tags: scala, comparable

Why does Scala's `RichInt` extends `Comparable[Int]` instead of `Comparable[RichInt]`?

I'm new to Scala. When browsing Scala library code, I noticed that class `RichInt` extends `ScalaNumberProxy[Int]`,
`ScalaNumberProxy` extends `OrderedProxy`, `OrderedProxy` extends `Ordered`, and `Ordered` extends `java.lang.Comparable`.
So my understanding is that `RichInt` (indirectly) extends `java.lang.Comparable[Int]`.

My question is why doesn't it extends `java.lang.Comparable[RichInt]`?

The reason that I raise this question is in Java, I would write code like this:

```java
class A implements Comparable<A> {

    @Override

    public int compareTo(A other) {
        //implement the method.
    }
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly we need to know `RichInt` is used for **supplying helper functions** for `Int` type by [implicit conversions](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/implicit-conversions.html) defined in the [Predef](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L596):

```
@inline implicit def intWrapper(x: Int) = new runtime.RichInt(x)
```

So you can use it like:

```
2.doubleValue()
2.shortValue()
...
```

And for your question: **why doesn't it extends java.lang.Comparable[RichInt]**

Because we actually is operating on the `Int` type, not the `RichInt` type.  like:

```
2.compare(3)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It is very helpful. I still have one question: what will happen if it extends java.lang.Comparable[RichInt]? Thank you for your kindly help.

Comment: if **extends java.lang.Comparable[RichInt]**, this will bound **Comparable** function(`compareTo`) in **RichInt type**. but actually `RichInt` is for rich functions in **Int** type not **RichInt** type.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So my understanding is that if **RichInt extends java.lang.Comparable[RichInt]**, **Int** type would not be **Comparable**.